# How can I subscribe user to a topic for notifications as soon as app starts up the android app?

Tags: android

How can I subscribe user to a topic for notifications as soon as app starts up?

I have an app I want to subscribe all those that they will install the app automatically on firebase messaging so that i can send them notification on ANDROID STUDIO

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Firebase Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic), you can simply call `subscribeToTopic` in your main activity's `onCreate`. To do this, you can add this line:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic_name");
```

If you would like to take some action after subscribing, you can add a listener that will get called when the subscription action is complete. For example (in Java):

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic_name")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // do something, such as showing a Toast to the user
            } else {
                // subscribing failed for some reason, maybe perform some error-handling
            }
        }
    });
```

There are more examples in the documentation above, including a Kotlin example (you didn't specify which language you were using, so I made an assumption), which you may find useful. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

for more information read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)